# Why does the iPhone load a black screen after the launch screens?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have been creating my first iOS app for iPhone (iOS 8) since last year (iOS 7).

My iPhone app launches perfectly, loads the launch images properly, and then loads up a black screen. You can see the status bar at the top as well. It stays on this screen. It should be loading my main selected `UIViewController`.

My main interface is set properly and my info.plist file seems look fine.

I am not using storyboards. I prefer to use NIBs (I am old school).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{ // Override point for customization after application launch. 
sleep(1); 
return YES; 
}
```

I do not hit `viewDidLoad` in my root `UIViewController`.

Comment: Adding a rant if you are not 110% sure that it's not your fault is always a bit risky...

Comment: Do you ever hit viewDidAppear in your root viewcontroller?

Comment: How are we supposed to know if you didn't even include any code ?

Comment: And what's the content of `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`? Anything `window`?

Comment: Include it in your question.

Comment: You're making the app wait a second before you allow it to present any UI and you are wondering why you get a black screen?...

Comment: Why are you calling `sleep(1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method needs to create a `UIWindow`, instantiate a view controller, and set that as the root view controller for your window. Then you should call `makeKeyAndVisible` on the window.